# JSON Array Displaying only last element Android TextView

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to list the JSON array and display in the TextViews, but somehow it shows only last element of the JSON array, please suggest the solution, here is my code.

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject jsonData = jObj.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray jsonarr = jsonData.getJSONArray("order_status_list");
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jsonarr.length(); i1++) {
    JSONObject c1 = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i1);
    txt_order_datetime.setText(c1.optString("status_datetime"));
    txt_order_status.setText(c1.optString("order_status_value"));
    txt_order_updatedby.setText(c1.optString("status_updated_by_user"));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You're calling `setText` on the **same** textview inside the loop everytime..

Comment: How can i declare array of TextViews then?

Comment: use append(..) instead of setText(..)

Comment: consider using a listview or a recyclerview (plenty of tutorials out there)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @sector11, you can use

```
txt_order_datetime.append(c1.optString("status_datetime"));
```

Comment: append will add items in loop to trail fo text view

Comment: or as @sector11 said use - txt_order_datetime.append(c1.optString("status_datetime"));

Comment: @AmbujKathotiya u changed answer after my comment.

Comment: @sector11 Yes because I realized that my answer would create duplicates. Forgot to clear the old text. Sorry.

Comment: Y do u want to get text set empty then compose new string its highly inefficient, u must use append in this case, otherwise what the purpose of append other than this i dont see any use case?

Comment: @sector11 actually I did not use append till now so I didn't know about that function. Sorry for that. I just shared what I knew.